# Copy csv values to another csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm copying the contents of a csv file and writing these to another so I can modify it later but can't figure out what the simple solution is. I thought I could keep the input `csv_file` and output `writer` files open while copying the contents, don't know if that's a good idea. My code

```
import csv, os

file_path = 'path/to/file.csv'
output_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file_path)) + '/'

with open(file_path) as csv_file:
    data_source = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    with open(output_path + 'results.csv', 'w', newline='') as writer:
        for line in data_source:
            writer.writerow(line)
```

This is the error I get:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writerow'
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thank you, never used a debugger before but if it helps with all sorts of problems, I will download one.

Comment: If you want to copy the full content of the csv file, it is simpler to copy the file.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks but I need to make changes to some values so thought it might be better to copy the values, change what needs to be changed and then dump the result into another csv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object that you think is the writer is not. Instead, you should construct the writer separately.

```
with open(file_path) as csv_file:
    data_source = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    with open(output_path + 'results.csv', 'w', newline='') as results_file:
        data_sink = csv.writer(results_file) #This is the important line
        for line in data_source:
            data_sink.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying the problem and providing a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code and see if this works?

```
import csv, os

file_path = 'path/to/file.csv'
output_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file_path)) + '/'

with open(file_path) as csv_file:
    data_source = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    f = open(output_path + 'results.csv', 'w', newline='')
    with f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for line in data_source:
            writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: @jim If this answer solved your issue, may I ask you to validate this as a correct answer? This helps others facing the same issue to get help

Comment: I used the solution given by code11 and I think it's only fair if I accept his answer. But I have upvoted yours.

Answer (score -1):

The error means that there is no method for writerow for the writer.

Comment: I was aware of that thanks, I wanted to know why the error occured and how it could be solved.